# How to customize error when unique is not respected in a Prop() in a Schema using Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, mongoose-schema, database-schema

I'm using NestJs to create an Api with mongoDB and mongoose, and here is my user schema :

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose";


@Schema({
  timestamps: true
})
export class User {
  @Prop()
  name: string;

  @Prop({
    required: true,
    unique: true
  })
  email: string;

  @Prop()
  password: string;
}
```

And i want to set a custom message when the Prop() email is not unique, because for now it only returns me an error500. Any ideas ?? thankyou !

i tried :

```
@Prop({
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    message:'test'
  })
```

but of course it won't work that way. I don't get where i can put it. thank you